# In a monad transformer, why is the known monad the inner one?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

For example, `MaybeT` is defined as:

```
newtype MaybeT m a =
  MaybeT { runMaybeT :: m (Maybe a)}
```

But not:

```
newtype MaybeT m a =
  MaybeT { runMaybeT :: Maybe (m a) }
```

Why is this?

Comment: Because we transform the `Maybe` monad, and not what the `Maybe` contains?

Comment: I think this has been answered somewhere before, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 8):

After expanding newtypes, we have `join :: Monad m => m (Maybe (m (Maybe a))) -> m (Maybe a)` in the first case and `join :: Monad m => Maybe (m (Maybe (m a))) -> Maybe (m a)` in the second.

To implement the first `join` you need a way to distribute `Maybe` over `m`: `dist1 :: Monad m => Maybe (m a) -> m (Maybe a)` :

```
join1 :: m (Maybe (m (Maybe a))) -> m (Maybe a)
join1 = fmap join . join . fmap dist1
```

To implement the second `join` you need the opposite distributive law `dist2 :: Monad m => m (Maybe a) -> Maybe (m a)`

```
join2 :: Maybe (m (Maybe (m a))) -> Maybe (m a)
join2 = fmap join . join . fmap dist2
```

`dist1` is easy to implement (I'll leave proving the monad transformer laws to you):

```
dist1 :: Monad m => Maybe (m a) -> m (Maybe a) 
dist1 = sequenceA
```

`dist2` is not so easy. It can't be done for an arbitrary `Monad`. As a counterexample, let's pick `m` to be the "reader" monad `(->) r`:

```
dist2 :: (r -> Maybe a) -> Maybe (r -> a)
```

Since you don't have access to an `r`, the only implementation of `dist2` that'll typecheck is `const Nothing`, which clearly won't satisfy the monad laws.

Comment: I think it's easier to see the problem by focusing on `join2` directly, rather than trying to reason too deeply about how it must decompose. We can pattern match on the argument, and then we need `m (Maybe (m a)) -> Maybe (m a)`. The only non-trivial choice is `Just`, which leads to `m (Maybe (m a)) -> m a`, which smells like trouble.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at `StateT` might be instructive:

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT { runStateT :: s -> m (a,s) }
```

Here the state is neither "inner" nor "outer", but its type is interleaved with the monad it is transforming, some bits inside, some outside.  And indeed

```
newtype ReaderT r m a = ReaderT { runReaderT :: r -> m a }
```

is all "outer".  So it depends on what transformer it is.  There's probably some category theory that at least partially explains this interleaving, I'm curious to know about it (intelligentsia?).

Contrast with applicative functors, for which

```
newtype Compose f g a = Compose { getCompose :: f (g a) }
```

is an applicative as well, so there is always a clear "inner/outer" relationship.  You could make an applicative-only `StateT`, and finding its structure by `Compose (State s)`:

```
ApplicativeStateT s f a = s -> (s, f a)
```

In fact, there's another one if you compose on the right:

```
ApplicativeStateT' s f a = f (s -> (s,a))
```

But monads have no such regularity.

Comment: I suspect the names we give some transformers may suggest a false pattern. We name `StateT` after `State` and `ReaderT` after `Reader`, etc, which seems to suggest a one-to-one relationship of some kind. But monads and monad transformers are really quite different, as evidenced by the various things that profess to be the "right" list monad transformer. "`ListT` done right", pipes/conduit/streaming/machines/coroutines, and `LogicT` (and the reflection-without-remorse version of `LogicT`) all seem to have legitimate claims to the title.